# Storage event not executed in WinForms web browser control

Tags: c#, winforms, web-control

I have custom WinForm web browser control that works fine in most cases. The problem I'm having is connected with localstorage events.

When adding a listener to the storage event (javascript):

```
window.addEventListener('storage', eventHandler, false)
```

the eventHandler function is never called. I have tried this with more than one window (hosting the web browser control) opend, but it does not work. If I open a regular browser and my custom browser, it will only trigger the storage event in the regular web browser if I write to local storage in the custom web browser, not the other way around.

Listening to the storagecommit event works ok:

```
window.addEventListener('storagecommit', eventHandler, false)
```

but that is only triggerd in the browser that wrote to local storage.

If anyone can provide some help it would be very appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I can access the localStorage variables, just no event.  I hope I'm not going to be stuck having to run a SetTimeout function to poll a localStorage variable.